# How to close angular server from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, child-process

I am making a web page using angular 6.0.8 with the cli too. I was able to successfully start the server using nodejs Child Process like this

```
var child=children.exec("ng serve",{},function(error,stdin,stdout){
  console.log('server terminated: '+error);
});
```

Then when I try to close the server like this

```
child.kill("SIGKILL");
```

It cuts off the connection between the server and my nodejs program but the server doesnt actually close until the host nodejs program does even thought the child process now registers as killed. I also tried to close it by connecting to the readline of the child process but that seemed to just cause more errors. this is what I tried

```
var childrl=readline.createInterface({stdin:child.stdin,stdout:child.stdout});
childrl.write(null,{ctrl:true,name:"c"});
```

the error it gave me is that `input.on` is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Node.JS's `child_process` to spawn a new process something like below:-

```
var angular = require('child_process').spawn('ng', ['serve']);
```

When you need to close the angular server, you may use something like below:-

```
angular.kill('SIGINT');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: using spawn instead of exec give me an error "ENOENT"

Comment: my guess would be that spawn is expecting a input output stream that the ng serve doesnt support

Comment: If you need to listen to the logs of the process, then you need to listen to `stdout` in your parent process. Well, could you please let me know the error that you encountered?

Comment: It gave the error enoent which doesnt make much sense in this context considering it worked with exec

Comment: I tried it in another context and it gave this error "kill EINVAL"  when it tried to kill the process. it also gives the error enoent when I dont try to kill it in that context so spawn isnt starting the server

Comment: I tried starting the server using the command. I have just edited the answer. Please refer. Right usage `spawn('ng', ['serve']);`. It is no longer giving that error. Let me know now if it solves.

Comment: I am now able to start the angular server and kill it using the above commands. Kindly verify at your end.

Comment: It works on linux although it is still a bit glitchy on my windows but that is probably due to what commands are available by default in windows and that could probably be fixed by pointing it directly to the executable file or taking steps to make sure ng is available in the path

Comment: Glad it helped. :)